# Pyspark Broadcast join

Tags: sql, pyspark

can anyone help in to understand the behaviour of the below query. why there is a broadcast join happening as shown in the physical plan but i am not doing any broadcast join in the query.

query:

> SELECT count(*) FROM table
> WHERE date_id in (select max(date_id) from table)

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[count(1)], output=[count(1)#17L])
+- Exchange SinglePartition
  +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_count(1)], output=[count#20L])
   +- *(2) Project
     +- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [date_id#14], [max(date_id)#16], LeftSemi, BuildRight
      :- *(2) FileScan parquet table[date_id#14] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: CatalogFileIndex[gs://data/features/smart_subs/pipeline/s..., PartitionCount: 14, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<>
      +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
        +- SortAggregate(key=[], functions=[max(date_id#14)], output=[max(date_id)#16])
         +- Exchange SinglePartition
           +- SortAggregate(key=[], functions=[partial_max(date_id#14)], output=[max#22])
            +- *(1) FileScan parquet table[date_id#14] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: CatalogFileIndex[gs:/data/features/smart_subs/pipeline/s..., PartitionCount: 14, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<>
```

Comment: `WHERE date_id in (select max(date_id) from table)` is the hash join. you should avoid subqueries of this type due to this very reason. instead, calculate the max using a window and filter it

Comment: @samkart something like this?  SELECT count(*) over (partition by date_id order by date_id desc) FROM table limit 1

Comment: no, you'll need to get the max value using the window function and then do `where date_id = <the max window column>` as the filter

Comment: SELECT MAX(date_id) OVER (ORDER BY date_id ASC) AS max_date FROM table;

Comment: please post a different question to get an on-point solution for this!

Answer (score 2):

Here in this screenshot you can see that in databricks they have explained using subqueries will be making a Broadcast Nested Loop join.

[image]

For further information, you can read this article:
https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2728434780191932/1483312212640900/6987336228780374/latest.html